# How to modify the elements of an array of GtkWidget's with a callback

Tags: c, arrays, struct, callback, gtk

I need to write a callback that would change the font color of the labels stored in an array of GtkWidget's.

Code in it's current state is here https://github.com/dustynine/colta-gtk/blob/struct/src/main.c

In the function that initializes the interface my array looks like this:

```
GtkWidget *cells[CELLS];
for (int i=0; i<CELLS; i++) {
    cells[i] = gtk_label_new("██");
}
```

Connected callback to the button:

```
g_signal_connect(
    G_OBJECT(button),
    "clicked",
    G_CALLBACK(encode),
    make_data(plaintext, key, cells)
);
```

`make_data()` is a function that returns a struct with callback's arguments:

```
struct passed_widgets {
    GtkWidget *plaintext;
    GtkWidget *key;
    GtkWidget **cls;
};

gpointer make_data(GtkWidget *text, GtkWidget *key, GtkWidget *cells[CELLS]) {
    static struct passed_widgets pw;
    pw.plaintext = text;
    pw.key = key;
    pw.cls = cells;
    return (gpointer) &pw;
}
```

And inside the callback itself I have this:

```
static void encode(GtkButton *button, gpointer *data) {
    struct passed_widgets *pw;
    GdkColor color;
    pw = (struct passed_widgets *) data;

    gdk_color_parse("#07d9d9", &color);
    gtk_widget_modify_fg(GTK_WIDGET(pw -> cls[0]), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
}
```

Compiler doesn't complain (aside from the warnings that color related stuff is deprecated) but when I actually push the button Gtk reports this:

```
(colta-gtk:3993): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type 'GInterface' in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(colta-gtk:3993): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_modify_fg: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I picked around in gdb for a bit and according to `explore pw -> cls[0]`:

```
'pw -> cls[0]' is a pointer to a value of type 'GtkWidget'
```

So, how do I make this work as intended? I have a suspicion that I'm either incorrectly assigning the array to the struct (but this is the only way the program worked) or incorrectly accessing it when trying to modify it at the end off the callback.

---

**EDIT:** I rewrote the program as liberforce suggested. Created a struct for my gui:

```
struct template {
    GtkWidget *window;
    ...
    GtkWidget *plaintext;
    GtkWidget *cells[CELLS];
};
```

Now I just pass this struct that I instantiated as `gui` to callback:

```
g_signal_connect(
    G_OBJECT(gui.button),
    "clicked",
    G_CALLBACK(encode),
    &gui
);
```

But I can't get anything to work in the encode() function anymore:

```
static void encode(GtkButton *button, gpointer data) {
    gchar *plaintext;
    struct template *pw;

    pw = (struct template *) data;

    plaintext = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(pw -> plaintext));
    printf("   plaintext contents: %s\n", plaintext);
```

Once again I just don't understand what is wrong. Compiler gives no warnings, according to gdb the types match, but when I run the program and use the callback it gives me that:

```
(colta-gtk:21589): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_get_buffer: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed

(colta-gtk:21589): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_buffer_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
```

---

Addresses are as follows:

```
gui.plaintext address: 0x55babcfc6290
gui address: 0x7ffd13fe8a88
&gui address: 0x7ffd13fe8910
data address: 0x7ffd13fe8910
pw address: 0x7ffd13fe8910
*pw address: 0x7ffd13fe8a88
pw -> plaintext address: (nil)
```

`*pw -> plaintext` causes Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. I create the struct prototype outside the `main()`

```
struct template {
    GtkWidget *window;
    ...
    GtkWidget *plaintext;
    GtkWidget *cells[CELLS];
};
```

Then in the callback that is called on the "activate" signal of the app I do this:

```
static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    static struct template gui;

    gui.plaintext = gtk_entry_new();
    printf("gui.plaintext address: %p\n", gui.plaintext);

    g_signal_connect(
        G_OBJECT(gui.button),
        "clicked",
        G_CALLBACK(encode),
        &gui
    );
```

and in the encode callback I have this

```
static void encode(GtkButton *button, gpointer data) {
    gchar *plaintext;
    struct template *pw;

    pw = (struct template *) data;

    plaintext = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(pw -> plaintext));
    printf("   plaintext contents: %s\n", plaintext);

    GdkColor color;
    gdk_color_parse("#ff0000", &color);
    gtk_widget_modify_fg(GTK_WIDGET(pw -> cells[0]), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, 
    &color);
}
```

Now everything works as intended. Basically I fixed my problem by adding `static` to `struct template gui` declaration in the `activate` callback. I'll leave the link to the working version of the file on github for future reference. Thanks liberforce for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you were using GtkApplication. Allocating on the stack works in the main if you use pass your the adress of your struct as the `user_data` when connecting to the `activate` signal. Or you can declare it as static, but don't do that in a callback handler, do it at the top of the file, so one can see the objects that are global to the file. You can also create the struct on the heap with `g_new`. The important this is that your gui struct must have the same lifetime as your application.

Comment: This means that if you declare the struct on the stack in a callback, it is destroyed when you exit the callback: you're tracking a pointer to its location but once the stack is modified that space is overwritten.

Comment: BTW, you shoul also try to switch to a real build system. For example your build script didn't work for me, because I have `bash`, but not `sh`. The Meson build system is the recommended build system for GTK/GNOME projects: http://mesonbuild.com/ . For example Meson would have enabled `-Wall` for you to have a reasonnable set of warnings enabled (and you should ALWAYS use that as a minimum). You might want to give a look at my repo at https://github.com/liberforce/metrognome , where I'm trying to keep up with best practice on writing a modern GTK+/C application.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely check it out. I'm still pretty new to C and GTK so your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of encode is wrong. It should be `gpointer data`, not `gpointer *data`. `gpointer` is already a typedef to `void *`.

Also, your `make_data` function should take a pointer to your struct argument, and just fill it. Don't use a static struct, as it makes code less reusable.

Usually I just create a `struct` in my `main` representing my gui, fill it, then pass the address of that stack-allocated struct (or sub-element of it) as the last arg of `g_signal_connect`.

One more thing is that there's no need to explicitely cast a pointer to `gpointer`, as every pointer can be implicitely cast to `gpointer`.

Comment: Did as you suggested and put all my gui into a struct, but I'm not able to make this variant work at all. I've added the details to the OP

Comment: Those assertions happen because you pass pointers that are not valid. Either it's not a valid pointer or it's a valid widget, but not of the right type you're expecting. `pw->plainext` is expected to be a GtkEntry. I see nothing wrong with the way you use it, so the bug may be in the way you initialize the struct.

Comment: Also, just call `gtk_entry_get_text` to get the text inside a `GtkEntry`.

Comment: I initialize the struct like this `struct template gui;` and then make a call: `gui.plaintext = gtk_entry_new();` and that's it.

Comment: Also, you said that `pw->plaintext` is expected to be a `GtkEntry` but I thought that calling `GTK_ENTRY()` casts it from a Widget to an Entry

Comment: First, try to debug and make sure the address of the widget you've created is the addres of the widget you're accessing in the callback. a `printf("addres: %p", my_widget)` after creation and when you're accessing it will be enough.

Comment: Then post the code where you create and initialize the structure with the newly created widgets. Equivalent to what you were doing in `make_data`.

Comment: Done. Instead of posting the code I've added the link to the file on GitHub. The file is just 170 SLOC so I guess this is allowed

Comment: I've just built your code (the "struct" branch), there's no segfault. However, you seem confused about how pointers work. Please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E

Comment: Ok, just saw your answer.